# Maximize the intersection of a target interval and a source interval with constant offset

Tags: geometry, discrete-optimization

Suppose we have a source interval $(x_1, x_2)$ and a target interval $(y_1, y_2)$. We want to find an integer $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that the new offset interval $(x_1-Nk, x_2-Nk)$ (for some $N\in\mathbb{R}$) maximizes the size of the intersection of the new interval and the target interval.

Formally we can write this as $$ \max_k\left( \min\{x_2 - Nk, y_2\} - \max\{x_1-Nk, y_1\} \right) $$

How can one go about solving this? I have found a closed solution when it is guaranteed the source interval can be offset to be entirely contained by the target, but I'm unsure how to generalise that result.

Comment: Is $N$ fixed as part of the input?

Comment: @RobPratt yes its fixed.

Answer (score 0):

First note that
$$ \max_k\left( \min\{x_2 - Nk, y_2\} - \max\{x_1-Nk, y_1\} \right) = \max_k\left( \min\{x_2 - Nk, y_2\} + \min\{-x_1+Nk, -y_1\} \right).$$
You can solve this maximin problem via mixed integer linear programming by introducing two decision variables to represent the $\min$ expressions.  Explicitly, the problem is to maximize $u+v$ subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
u &\le x_2 - Nk \\
u &\le y_2 \\
v &\le -x_1 + Nk \\
v &\le -y_1
\end{align}

Comment: Does this have a closed form solution?

Comment: The solution will not always be unique.  The objective value will be $0$ for all but a finite number of $k$, all of which are consecutive, so you can just loop over that interval for $k$ and take the best.